# WinForms Text Bugging

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm getting a weird bug where the text begins to disappear on my winforms application.  [image: Image of bug]

I've looked online for a solution but I'm not sure what the root cause of this is.  Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated.  I've never had anything like happen before.

Comment: Did you try deleting and re-adding the label or did you try different fonts?

Comment: are you running some thread in the background?

Comment: Deleting and re-adding the label doesn't fix the problem.  There shouldn't be any thread running in the background.  I've only made the interface.  I haven't added in the logic yet.

Comment: Are you using any special kind of label? Are you using a special or nonstandard font? Is there any code behind this form?

Comment: I'm using Arial normal.  No other program is being affected.  I've run other winforms applications I've written and none of them are experiencing this problem.  I think it has to do with the fact that I changed the tab index of the items.  The cursor isn't showing up in the focused textbox either.  I'll tinker with it some more.

Comment: Is the program stuck in some sort of endless loop that would keep the UI thread busy?  Does the cursor show up anywhere?  If the UI is painting odd and the cursor isn't showing up when it should be, I'd look into an issue with the UI thread being bogged down.

Comment: If you run the program on another computer, does the problem still reproduce? If yes, the problem is within your code (or the libraries you use). If not, the problem is related to your particular machine, in which case trouble-shooting would need to include diagnosing the state of your system configuration.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem on another machine.  I think the problem comes from the way focus is being assigned and the fact that I messed with the tab indexes.  I was able to remove the problem on one of the views by specifying all the tab actions from all possible objects.  I'll post an answer once I fully implement the fix and test it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the future that runs into this problem.  The buggy looking text comes from overlapping tab indexes and not having a 0 tab index on a panel.  Also try and keep them in order, so don't arbitrarily assign tab indexes like (50, 100, etc).

Basically don't get creative with the tab indexes unless you have to.

Comment: Glad to hear you found and smashed that critter :)